# PHP preg_match using 'or' delimiter

Tags: php, preg-match, delimiter

I'm trying to match a certain string of the url using `preg_match` but I need to match either one or the other string and I can't find the correct syntax.

What I'm using now is:

```
$is_url_en = preg_match ("/\b95\b/i", $iframeurl);
```

This searches for the number "95" in the url. However I also want to match "en" as well but I don't know how to use the 'or' delimiter. I've seen somewhere the following:

```
$is_url_en = preg_match ("/\b95\b/i|/\ben\b/i", $iframeurl);
```

...but it doesn't work. Any hints please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't repeat the `/` and `/i`. Those delimit the regex so they should only be there once.

```
$is_url_en = preg_match ("/\b95\b|\ben\b/i", $iframeurl);
```

You could then simplify this to:

```
$is_url_en = preg_match ("/\b(95|en)\b/i", $iframeurl);
```